# How to set a base url for markdown links in IPython?

Tags: python, html, markdown, ipython

I was happily setting

```
<head>
<base href="http://complex_url_to_local_wiki:port/path/" target="_blank" />
</head>
```

in a Markdown cell in my IPython html notebook (IPython 0.12) in order to be able to abbreviate links as`[wiki documentation](doc.html)` in Markdown cells.

But this makes saving the notebook impossible (saving is restored by `<base href='/'/>`).

Is there any (alternative) way to achieve what I am seeking? I know how to produce the URL from Python code by use of `IPython.core.display.HTML`[1], but it is considerably more convenient to inline the links in the Markdown documentation

Thanks,

Álvaro.

[1] The non-optimal solution producing the link from Python is pasted below in case it is useful for somebody or you have suggestions for improvement

```python
def wurl(x, text="Node {} in wiki",
            baseurl="http://complex_url_to_local_wiki:port/path/{}"):
    """Render a link on a base URL as html."""

    from IPython.core.display import HTML
    url_t = '<a href="{baseurl}" target="_blank">{text}</a>'
    return HTML(url_t.format(baseurl=baseurl.format(x), text=text.format(x)))
```

Comment: Markdown is entirely processed in the browser, so I guess any solution is going to involve Javascript.