# In Jekyll (ie. Markdown), can the base portion of a set URLs be shared among links?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

[The MD syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link) allows for two basic way to do links: `[title](link)` and `[title][reference]`.  The `[reference]` can be used multiple times in a document, but it is only for absolute URLs.

What if I'm doing a code blog and am frequently referencing API docs, so many URLs start the same, for example, `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/` as a base for `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html`.  Is there a way to modularize links like this?

Maybe there's another choice besides Markdown that's compatible with Jekyll?  A plugin?  This seems like it would be a common need.

Related:  [How to set a base url for markdown links in IPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030525/how-to-set-a-base-url-for-markdown-links-in-ipython)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use a link library (an include) that I can use in any post or page.

Note: if site is not at the root of a domain (eg: localhost/ or example.com/)
      and lives in a subfolder (eg: localhost/subfolder/) we need to
      prepend internal links with the value of **site.baseurl**

```
<!--- file : _includes/_links_library.markdown --->

<!--- POSTS --->
[welcome]: {{site.baseurl}}{% post_url 2014-09-09-welcome-to-jekyll %}

<!--- PAGES --->
[index]: {{site.baseurl}}/subfolder/
[file]: {{site.baseurl}}/subfolder/file.html

<!--- EXTERNAL PAGES --->
[jekyll]: http://jekyllrb.com/

<!--- ANDROID API REF --->
{% assign androidRef = "http://developer.android.com/reference/android" %}
[context]: {{ androidRef }}/content/Context.html
```

We then just have to include our library to use links like this :

```
---
front matter
---

Link to [welcome post][welcome]
Link to [index][]
Link to [Jekyll doc][jekyll]

{% include _links_library.markdown %}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I note for posterity that the `assigns` keyword is a part of the Liquid templating engine (not Markdown), and that the `assign` (and therefore the `include`) seem to need to come before the use of the variable.